# Disable edit and browse button in a custom dirpage if a function is checked

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a custom dirpage created and i know that i can disable the directory edition or the browse button with:

`custompagename.Buttons[0].Enabled := False; 
 custompagename.Edits[0].enabled:= False;`

But as the tittle says i only want to disable that option if a function is checked.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on what the function does or when is it called, for example? Maybe share part of your installer code, or something...

Comment: the function is like a task for installing a feature or something else like a shortcut: function installpro: Boolean;
begin
  Result := installerpro.Checked;
end;

Comment: So you want something like this, right? `if installpro then custompagename.Buttons[0].Enabled := False; custompagename.Edits[0].enabled:= False; end;`

Comment: Yeah, that worked fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. There's a function in Inno's Pascal Scripting Language that checks whether a specific task was checked by the user. It should be pretty straight forward. Here's the prototype for the function:

```
function IsTaskSelected(const Tasks: String): Boolean;
```

So all you need to do is make this check before performing any tweaks to your page:

```
if IsTaskSelected('your_task_name') then
begin
    custompagename.Buttons[0].Enabled := False; 
    custompagename.Edits[0].Enabled:= False;
end;
```

Let us know if that works for you. Hope it helped.